# Table django site doesn't exist

Tags: django

When I try to install a database into my local I used;

```
python manage.py syncdb --noinput
```

However, it gave;

```
Table 'lodging_zh.django_site' doesn't exist"
```

It gave the error at `Site.objects.get_current()` line. Probably it tries to reach the currenct_site on the database. However since database is empty, it gave an error.  Do you have any idea about this problem to solve?

Comment: Do you have any migrations specified in your settings?

Comment: What Django version are you using? If it's 1.7+, you should also run `python manage.py migrate --noinput`

Comment: I am using Django 1.8.5. python manage.py migrate --fake also gave the exactly the same result.

Comment: Using `--fake` with migrate won't help -- it will update the db as if the migration has already run. If this is a new project, it might be easiest to drop the db, and run `migrate` again.

Answer (score 2):

Probably something with migration order. You can try to remove `django.contrib.sites` from the `INSTALLED_APPS` and then syncdb. If that succeeds add `django.contrib.sites` and migrate again.

Alternatively you can add `'sites': 'my_app.sites_migrations` to `MIGRATION_MODULES` and then make migrations for this with `python manage.py makemigrations sites`. Then running `syncdb` might work as well.